# swingworker: how to clean up resources when canceling thread

Tags: java, ms-word, swingworker

I'm using SwingWorker to run a background task.

In `doInBackground()` I'm opening a MS Word Document and reading words. If the thread runs well, the Word Document will be closed. But if I cancel the thread using `swingworker.cancel(true)`, the thread will jump out of `doInBackground` and jump into the `done()` method, therefore the Word Document can not be closed.

Could anyone give me a clue to cleaning up the mess?

Answer (score 2):

Put your cleanup code in a `finally` block. That way, it will always run before exiting the `doInBackground()` function.

Comment: Doesn't Work? Put your clean up code in the finalize() method

Comment: @Shuo: "doesn't work" tells us little. It should work, it works for me,but if it doesn't work for you, you're probably using it wrong. Show your code, show your errors, else we can't help you.

Comment: as far as I konw,when a SwingWorker is canceled, done() is called before doInBackground() returns,actually doInBackground() is still working,what I want is that doInBackground could immediately stopped,not run until the 'finally code',cause doInBackground() has tons of work to do,it waits a long time to reach the 'finally code'

Comment: Then we're going to need a lot more detail about what your background task is doing. The JVM can't simply stop your running code, you need to put in some kind of interrupt mechanism.